# I am trying to stream a mp4 file using gstreamer on my local network on VLC media player

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am new to gstreamer and trying to play a mp4 file using gstreamer tools on VLC media player. Can you guys please tell me what might be possible wrong here

server code:

> gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=sample_mp4.mp4 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5010

Client code:

> gst-launch-1.0.exe -v udpsrc port=5010 ! application/x-rtp,media=(string)video, payload= (int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264 ! rtph264depay ! autovideosink

VLC SDP File:

> v=0
>       m=video
>       5010 RTP/AVP 96
>       c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
>       a=rtpmap:96 H264-ES/90000

Output at server side:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, parsed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, parsed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, parsed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, parsed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)316477758, timestamp-offset=(uint)4247400026, seqnum-offset=(uint)24506
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)316477758, timestamp-offset=(uint)4247400026, seqnum-offset=(uint)24506
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 4247400026
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 24506
>   Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
>   Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
>   New clock: GstSystemClock

Output at client side:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
>   Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
>   New clock: GstSystemClock
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264

Output while running VLC file:

> VLC can't recognize the input's format:
>   The format of 'file:///C:/Users/gayatri_t/Desktop/vlc_video.sdp' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.

Comment: What errors are you getting? We can help you if you can be more specific.

Comment: No error were displayed while running server command and client command, but while running the vlc.sdp file, the video is not playing.

Comment: Could you try running the server side again with `-v` parameter (i.e. `gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=sample_mp4_video.mp4 !  h264parse ! video/x-h264 !  rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5010 -v` )

Comment: I have attached the output logs displayed with -v option